# Can't get admin rights in newly bought laptop

Tags: windows-10, sync, administrator, microsoft-account

I had bought a new laptop(Windows 10) and set it up by making a new microsoft account. However, I forgot the password to the account. Thus, I went to settings and logged in using local account. Then I made a new microsoft account, logged in and set it up as the admin.

I had then deleted the original (The first account I set up after buying the laptop) from the laptop and from services like outlook, MS office etc. However, I faced a new difficulty.

I couldn't sync my settings in the control panel (Which is referred as "settings" In win 10). It showed up, "couldn't sync. Ask your administrator". What should I do now? Do I have to somehow log into the original account and set it up? Or is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Reset to factory settings. It will be the same as when you bought it. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/recovery-options-in-windows-10-31ce2444-7de3-818c-d626-e3b5a3024da5



> Reset your PC
>
> Important: If you’ve encrypted your device, you’ll need your BitLocker
> key to reset your PC If you don’t know your BitLocker key, see Find my
> BitLocker recovery key.
>
> Resetting reinstalls Windows 10, but lets you choose whether to keep
> your files or remove them, and then reinstalls Windows. You can reset
> your PC from Settings, the sign-in screen, or by using a recovery
> drive or installation media.
>
> Reset your PC from Settings
>
> 1.Select the Start  button, then select Settings  > Update & Security   > Recovery . Open Recovery settings
>
> 2.Under Reset this PC, select  Get started and then choose from the options and/or settings in the table below.
>
> Option
>
> What it does
>
> Keep my files > Change settings > Preinstalled apps On   ◾Reinstalls
> Windows 10 and keeps your personal files.
>
> ◾Removes apps and drivers you installed.
>
> ◾Removes changes you made to settings.
>
> ◾Restores any apps your PC manufacturer installed if your PC came with
> Windows 10.
>
> Keep my files > Change settings > Preinstalled apps Off   ◾Reinstalls
> Windows 10 and keeps your personal files.
>
> ◾Removes apps and drivers you installed.
>
> ◾Removes changes you made to settings.
>
> ◾Removes any apps your PC manufacturer installed.
>
> Remove everything   ◾Reinstalls Windows 10 and removes your personal
> files.
>
> ◾Removes apps and drivers you installed.
>
> ◾Removes changes you made to settings.
>
> ◾Removes any apps your PC manufacturer installed. (If your PC came
> with Windows 10, apps from your PC manufacturer will be reinstalled.)
>
> Note: Remove everything > Change settings gives you two options.
>
> Data erasure On removes files and cleans the drive. If you're planning
> to donate, recycle, or sell your PC, use this option. This might take
> an hour or two, but it makes it harder for other people to recover
> files you've removed.
>
> Data erasure Off just removes files. It takes less time, but is less
> secure.
>
> **Reset your PC from the sign-in screen**
>
> If you can't open Settings, you can reset your PC from the sign-in
> screen. Here’s how:
>
> 1.Press Windows logo key + L to get to the sign-in screen, and then restart your PC by pressing the Shift key while you select the Power 
> button > Restart in the lower-right corner of the screen.
>
> 2.Your PC will restart in the Windows Recovery Environment (WinRE) environment.
>
> 3.On the Choose an option screen, select Troubleshoot > Reset this PC, and then choose one of the options in the previous table.
>
> Choose an option screen in the Windows Recovery Environment.